# Why overflow hidden in this scenario not working like expected?

Tags: html, css

can someone point me why in this case `overflow:hidden` not working? I want to undurstand what am I doing wrong.

```css
* {
  background: #000;
}

div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content:center;
  height: 100vh;
}
.btn {
  display:block;
  background: #0000ff;
  margin: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 15px 35px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.btn::before {
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width:0;
  height:0;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: lightblue;
  pointer-events:none;
}
.btn:hover::before {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<a href="#" class="btn">
Click
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to prevent from overflowing?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to get rid of the vertical scroll on the `<body>` element, you can add `padding: 0; margin: 0` to your [universal selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Universal_selectors) (*).

The reason you were getting a vertical scroll bar on the body is that the `<body>` element, in most user agents, has a default margin of 8 pixels. Setting `margin: 0` in the universal selector (or the body declaration) will remove that default, 8px margin.

I also removed `overflow:hidden;` from the `.btn` declaration as it was serving no purpose.

```css
* {
  background: #000;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content:center;
  height: 100vh;
}
.btn {
  display:block;
  background: #0000ff;
  margin: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 15px 35px;
}
.btn::before {
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width:0;
  height:0;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: lightblue;
  pointer-events:none;
}
.btn:hover::before {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<a href="#" class="btn">
Click
</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The overflow in the btn wont work for the whole body you either add the `overflow:hidden;` in the `* {}` or add `margin:0; padding:0;`

```css
* {
  background: #000;
  overflow:hidden;
}

div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content:center;
  height: 100vh;
}
.btn {
  display:block;
  background: #0000ff;
  margin: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 15px 35px;
  
}
.btn::before {
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width:0;
  height:0;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: lightblue;
  pointer-events:none;
}
.btn:hover::before {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<a href="#" class="btn">
Click
</a>
</div>
```